# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer problem with image rotation

Tags: angular, pdf, orientation, image-rotation, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I have a File.pdf that contains just one image on a server.
When i download the File.pdf and open it with adobe, the image is displayed with the correct rotation in the pdf file.

When i open the File.pdf in https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html, the image is rotated correctly:
[mozilla pdf viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfEN1.jpg)

When i also open the same File.pdf in chrome pdf viewer, the image is rotated correctly:
[chrome pdf viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYjen.jpg)

The problem is when i open the File.pdf from ngx-extended-pdf-viewer within my application, the ngx-extended-pdf-viewer displays the image with wrong rotation.
[ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAX2X.png)

Expected Result:
ngx-extended-pdf-viewer display the image in File.pdf with the correct rotation

Error Messages: None

The code within my application is:

```
  <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer fxHide.sm fxHide.xs class="pdfViewer"
                           *ngIf="fileData.doc_Base64"
                           [base64Src]="fileData.doc_Base64"
                           useBrowserLocale="true"
                           height="30vh"
                           [textLayer]="true"
                           [showHandToolButton]="true"
                           [zoom]="'page-fit'"
                           [filenameForDownload]="fileData.doc_Name"
  ></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update to the latest version of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer. Around the time you've posted the question, I solved a image rotation bug. I assume it's fixed now.